# How to extract a substring using a regular expression

Tags: regex, dart

There is a text like:
...some text [wrong answer\#correct answer\wrong answer] some text...

I need to figure out how to extract two substrings from the text in square brackets (in different places, i.e. two regular expressions should result):

1. All wrong answers without \
2. Correct answers that begin with #, while excluding \ and #

At the same time, in place of correct and wrong answers, there can be a string of any size with any characters except [, ], \, #.
It is desirable that the number of possible answers does not affect the expression. For example, there may be several correct and incorrect answers. The order in which the answers stand may also change.
Any ideas how to do this using regEx?

Comment: Are there always the same number of answers?

Comment: You don't _need_ regex... what language are you using?

Comment: it is desirable that the number of possible answers does not affect the expression. For example, there may be several correct and incorrect answers.

Comment: M14 can you update your question with the tag of your coding language?

Comment: Sure. However, in this case need regex because I want to pass the regex patterns to another lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that we have one of the answers we need to check what symbol is before it. To do so we can use **Positive Lookbehind**
like this `(?<=Y)X`. Idea is something like "*find the **X** if there is a **Y** before it*". Then all we need is just to take all the text not matching special chars like `\`, `#`, `[` or `]` using `[^XYZ]` that matches everything besides `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

To fix the issue from the comment we also need to check what comes next after the answer. There are 2 options: `\` or `]`. Now we are going to use **Positive Lookahead** which is like **Lookbehind** but checks the text after `X`. Example `X(?=Y)` means "*find the **X** if there is a **Y** after it*".

**Final patterns are:**

- Wrong answers: `(?<=\\|\[)[^\\#\[\]]+(?=\\|\])`
- Correct answers: `(?<=#)[^\\#\[\]]+(?=\\|\])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The proposed patterns are almost perfect for me, but there is a problem with the fact that they work on the text that is not included in the square quotes. For example, the text may have the following result: ...some text [**wrong answer** \#correct answer \ **wrong answer**] \ **text**. Can you advise me how best to fix it

Comment: Updated the answer to fix your issue.